# why highchart boundbox doesn't indicate axis label overlap?

Tags: highcharts

From the jsfiddle example(http://jsfiddle.net/daxu/md2zk/74/), you can see that the last two labels are overlapping.
However, from the bound box of the label, I got values such as:

```
Last label:   X: 614  Y: 168 
height: 10
width: 34
x: 0
y: -8

Previous label:  X: 575.160409556314  Y: 168 
Object
height: 10
width: 34
x: 0
y: -8
```

Base on these values, those two labels just shouldn't overlap 
as 575+34 <614?

Can someone help? I am not allowed to have two lines in x axis label, as data is dynamic, I can't really preset the label in a nice way at design time.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable [padding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.padding) parameter which is defaulty enabled.

Comment: Hi I set padding to be 0, but the output is still the same? What I want is to get find a way to detect overlap (as we data is dynamic)

Comment: Instead of width, try to refer to textWidth which is available in tick.label object.

Comment: textWidth  is like 91 and width is 34. From the generated svg file, I can see that 34 is right. Although none of these values are correct in my formula.

Comment: In textWidth you have a 45, so when you sum 575 + 45 then you have 620, which is bigger than 614.

Comment: the thing is that if I found a overlap, I was trying to use previous.label.textStr = ""; (previous is the second last tick) and hope this will remove the label from drawing (as it overlaps with the last one), however, there is no impact with setting it.

Comment: anyone got some idea?